# MVC action name exposed when javascript disabled

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

We're working on an MVC application at the moment and we're running into some issues with our URL's.

We have two simple action methods in a controller:

```
public PartialViewResult Index(ListingPagePress currentPage)
    {
        var model = new ListingPagePressViewModel(currentPage);

        var pressReleaseChildren = GetData(currentPage, 0);
        model.PressReleasePages = pressReleaseChildren;
        model.TotalPages = 3;

        return PartialView(model);
    }

    public PartialViewResult PressReleaseList(ListingPagePress currentPage, int pageNo)
    {
        IEnumerable<PressReleasePageViewModel> data = GetData(currentPage, pageNo);
        return PartialView(data);
    }
```

The PressReleaseList is rendered using an action, i.e.:

@Html.Action("PressReleaseList", new { pageNo = 0 })

and then we have some simple pagination:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.TotalPages; i++)
{
@Ajax.ActionLink(i.ToString(), "Index",
        new { pageNo = i },
        new AjaxOptions
        {
            UpdateTargetId = "pressReleaseTable",
            OnBegin = "OnAjaxRequestBegin",
            OnFailure = "OnAjaxRequestFailure",
            OnSuccess = "OnAjaxRequestSuccess",
            OnComplete = "OnAjaxRequestComplete"
        })
        }
```

The unobtrustive ajax is working just fine. The problem is, if the client has javascript disabled they end up navigating to the partialview via a horrid url such as:

http://example.com/press-releases/PressReleaseList/?pageNo=1

Whereas we want to retain the true URL structure which would be: http://example.com/press-releases/?pageNo=1

How do we acheive this? Is mapping a route the only possibility? That would be quite hard fro us because we're working with a CMS, so we never know what the exact url prefix would be because the User could change the url of "press-releases".

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Regards
dotdev

Comment: Why is it important to support a client with disabled javascript? Sound like a problem from 10 years ago. I wonder why do you even care?

Comment: Mainly because search engines do not have Javascript enabled, so they would index the url with the ActionNAme appended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what you are trying to achieve is the removal of the Action name from the URL.

Index method achieves this because it has a default action name of Index.

So what you can do it overload the Index action by take `int? pageNo` as a parameter. If it's not null, then branch, so it ends up something like this:

```
public PartialViewResult Index(ListingPagePress currentPage, int? pageNo)
{
    if (pageNo == null)
    {
        var model = new ListingPagePressViewModel(currentPage);

        var pressReleaseChildren = GetData(currentPage, 0);
        model.PressReleasePages = pressReleaseChildren;
        model.TotalPages = 3;

        return PartialView(model);
    }
    else
    {
        IEnumerable<PressReleasePageViewModel> data = GetData(currentPage, pageNo);
        return PartialView(data);
    }
}
```

You can make it a bit more separated by implementing an actionselector and making the second call go to a different method by using a different verb or a different header.

As a side note MVC vNext support method overloading, so you could just split the method based on the extra parameters.

Comment: Thanks Yishai - your post lead me to an eventual solution, overloading the Index method.

Comment: I assume using an ActionSelector? Also note (and I realize it might not be 100% applicable in your case) that if you care about url shape you can also use attribute routing